# how to print the output in certain order?

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

I am trying to extracting the data from an XML document and print it in a certain order, but I'm unable to print in that order

**Input XML**

```
<xml>
  <service>
    <title>split xml</title>
    <main>
      <doc id="001">
        <title>doc1</title>
        <delt id="0001">
          <title>delt1</title>
          <text>num1</text>
        </delt>
        <delt id="0002-A">
          <title>delt2</title>
          <text>num1</text>
        </delt>
      </doc>
      <doc id="002">
        <title>doc2</title>
        <delt id="0003">
          <title>delt3</title>
          <text>num1</text>
        </delt>
        <delt id="0004">
          <title>delt4</title>
          <text>num1</text>
        </delt>
      </doc>
    </main>
  </service>
</xml>
```

**output printing in this order**

```
0001
delt1
0002-A
delt2
0003
delt3
0004
delt4
```

**output needed**

```
delt1   0001    
delt2   0002-A
delt3   0003    
delt4   0004
```

**This is my code**

```
use File::Find;
use XML::LibXML;
use Data::Dumper;

my $path = "data.xml";
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
my $dom = $parser->parse_file($path) or die;

for my $sample ( $dom->findnodes('//delt/@id|//delt/title') ) {
  print $sample->textContent(),"\t";  
  print "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do as you ask. It's simply a matter of finding all the `delt` elements and then extracting the `id` attribute and the `title` child element of each and printing them.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
my $dom    = $parser->load_xml(IO => \*DATA) or die;

for my $delt ( $dom->findnodes('/xml/service/main/doc/delt') ) {
  my $id = $delt->getAttribute('id');
  my $title = $delt->findvalue('title');
  printf "%-8s%s\n", $title, $id;
}

__DATA__
<xml>
  <service>
    <title>split xml</title>
    <main>
      <doc id="001">
        <title>doc1</title>
        <delt id="0001">
          <title>delt1</title>
          <text>num1</text>
        </delt>
        <delt id="0002-A">
          <title>delt2</title>
          <text>num1</text>
        </delt>
      </doc>
      <doc id="002">
        <title>doc2</title>
        <delt id="0003">
          <title>delt3</title>
          <text>num1</text>
        </delt>
        <delt id="0004">
          <title>delt4</title>
          <text>num1</text>
        </delt>
      </doc>
    </main>
  </service>
</xml>
```

**output**

```
delt1   0001
delt2   0002-A
delt3   0003
delt4   0004
```

Comment: Note that recent versions of XML::LibXML::Element overload hash dereferencing, so `$delt->getAttribute('id')` can be written as `$delt->{id}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Modern::Perl;
use XML::LibXML;

my $path = "data.xml";
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
my $dom = $parser->parse_file($path) or die;

my %items = map { $_->textContent() } $dom->findnodes('//delt/@id|//delt/title');
print sort map { "$items{$_}\t$_\n" } keys %items;
```

Output:

```
delt1   0001
delt2   0002-A
delt3   0003
delt4   0004
```

Comment: *`Argument "0002-A" isn't numeric in sort`*

Comment: Removed loop, using now map. Concise/shorter version